Showing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{n}{p-1}-\left[(\frac{n}{n+1})^p+(\frac{n}{n+2})^p+\cdots\right]\right\}=\frac12$ for $p>1$
For $ p > 1$, show that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} - \left[ \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^p + \left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^p + \cdots\right] \right\}= \frac{1}{2}$$
I could compute the limit of the sum (up to the $n$-th term) divided by $n$ using the integral method:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{n}{n+k}\right)^p = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x)^p} = \frac{1-2^{1-p}}{p-1}$$
Note: This is exercise 8, on page 22, from Mathematical Analysis: Functions, Limits, Series, Continued Fractions (ebook link via amazon.com), edited by L. A. Lyusternik and A. R. Yanpol'skii, first edition (1965).
Comment: I write this after seeing the nice solutions below from @Svyatoslav and @AxelT. However, it would be great to see a more elementary solution, without employing sophisticated methods. By elementary, I mean something at high-school level let's say.

As per your computation, shouldn't the limit be $+\infty$? I suppose the limit should be $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg[\frac{1}{p-1} - \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigg(\frac{n}{n+k}\bigg)^p \bigg]$$ But then, the answer would be $\frac{2^{1-p}}{p-1}$ and not $\frac12$. Can you provide a link to the book you mentioned? I'm not getting it on the internet.

Yeah, I don't think this is true. Is there a reason you think it is?

Do note that my result does not solve the question, since I have a 1/n term under the sum. While the original question looks a bit different. That was my difficulty.

@ThomasAndrews: I actually tested the limit in Python and seems to be true.

@MathGuy The limit as you wrote it would follow from the integral indeed. Yet, the original limit is different (and seems to be correct too).

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac n{n+k}\right)^p=\frac{n^p}{\Gamma(p)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^{p-1}e^{-(n+k)x}dx=\frac{n^p}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{p-1}e^{-nx}}{e^x-1}dx$$
$$=\frac{n^p}{\Gamma(p)}\frac1{n^p}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{p-1}e^{-t}}{e^\frac tn-1}dt=\frac1{\Gamma(p)}\left(n\Gamma(p-1)-\frac12\Gamma(p)+O\Big(\frac1n\Big)\right)$$
We only have to prove that we are allowed to change the order of summation and integration, what is straightforward.

@Svyatoslav   Can you elaborate a bit on the last equality for clarity? What expansion do you do? If you consider $t/n$ very small how does that hold for large $t$ for given $n$?Thanks

The function $,\frac1n\frac{t^{p-1}e^{-t}}{e^\frac tn-1}$ is dominated by $,\frac1n\frac{t^{p-1}e^{-t}}{\frac tn}=t^{p-2}e^{-t}$, so you can apply the dominated convergence theorem and take the limit under the integral sign. The apply the DCT again. Or, use the Watson' lemma - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma

Using Euler-Maclaurin summation one has
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+k} \right)^p &= \int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+x}\right)^p dx + \frac{1}{2}\left(n/(n+1)\right)^p + \frac{B_2}{2!}\left(pn^p\left(n+1/n \right)^{-p-1} \right) + ... \\
&= n\int_{1/n}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^p dx + \frac{1}{2}\left(1+1/n\right)^{-p} + \frac{p}{12n}\left(\left(1+1/n^2\right)^{-p-1} \right) +... \\
&= n\int_{1/n}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^p dx + \frac{1}{2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$.
As for the integral,
\begin{align}
\int_{1/n}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^p dx &= \int_{1+1/n}^{\infty} x^{-p}dx 
= \frac{(1+1/n)^{1-p}}{p-1}\to \frac{1}{p-1}
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$ (and $p>1$) and the result follows.

For clarity, would you add the next summation term (so we can see it goes to 0)?
The Beta function is in the alternative form as in Eq. (22) from MathWorld (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html), but the integral can be done also without.

@Chip, I added the next term from the Euler-Maclaurin summation, I hope it is clear enough.

Nice work, thanks!

Incomplete. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^\infty\Box=\int_0^\infty\Box=:L$ implies only $n\int_{1/n}^\infty\Box=nL+\color{red}{o(n)}$, not $nL+\color{blue}{o(1)}$.

Thanks @metamorphy, I changed the part with the integral.

This doesn't resolve the issue (you've just changed the way the limit is computed). In fact you have $$\int_{1/n}^\infty\Box=\int_0^\infty\Box+O(1/n),$$
and this $O(1/n)$ gets multiplied by $n$, which would invalidate the result ($1/2$), if... there are no mistakes earlier. But there is one: the last term in the first line of your answer contains $(n+\color{red}{1/n})^{-p-1}$ instead of the correct $(n+\color{blue}{1})^{-p-1}$. (I didn't try to fix it; looks like E.-M. actually fails.)

An "elementary" approach. If $a_n=O(n^{-p})$ as $n\to\infty$ (with $p>1$), then $\color{blue}{\sum_{k>n}a_k=O(n^{1-p})}$ (shown by comparison with an integral, or via $a_n=O\big((n-1)^{1-p}-n^{1-p}\big)$ like below).
Now, using the binomial series,
$$
(k-1)^{1-p}-k^{1-p}=k^{1-p}\left[\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{1-p}-1\right]\\=(p-1)k^{-p}+\frac{p(p-1)}2k^{-1-p}+O(k^{-2-p})
$$
as $k\to\infty$; doing $\sum_{k>n}$ and using the $\color{blue}{\text{above}}$, we get
$$
n^{1-p}=(p-1)\sum_{k>n}k^{-p}+\frac{p-1}2\ p\sum_{k>n}k^{-1-p}+O(n^{-1-p}).
$$
The second sum is $O(n^{-p})$ by the $\color{blue}{\text{above}}$; replacing $p$ by $1+p$, we get
$$
n^{-p}=p\sum_{k>n}k^{-1-p}+O(n^{-1-p})
$$
which, substituted into the preceding equality, yields
$$
n^{1-p}=(p-1)\sum_{k>n}k^{-p}+\frac{p-1}2n^{-p}+O(n^{-1-p})
$$
or, after multiplication by $n^p/(p-1)$ and rearranging,
$$
\frac{n}{p-1}-n^p\sum_{k>n}k^{-p}=\frac12+O(n^{-1}).
$$

Thumbs up, nice work!
